# C++/CLI implement interface automatically

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

In a C# program in VS2008, I can point at the name of the interface and say 'automatically implement".

Is there an equivalent option for C++/CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none built in to Visual Studio, but some third-party plugins provide such features for C++.  I think that Whole Tomato's Visual Assist X includes it.